How to use React Native Reanimated or React Native Skia to make a shape move along a given path
As shown in the figureExample image, how to make the red ball move along the black path? And it can apply animation effects such as React Native Reanimated withSpring.
In React Native Skia, I try to do things like this:
const progress = useSharedValue(0);
const geo = new PathGeometry(path);
const totalLength = geo.getTotalLength();
const transform = useDerivedValue(() => {
const currentLen = interpolate(progress.value, [0, 1], [0, totalLength]);
const pos = geo.getPointAtLength(currentLen);
return translate({x:pos.x,y:pos.y});
});
const handlePress = () => {
progress.value = withSpring(1);
};


But received an error message:
ReanimatedError: [Reanimated] Trying to access property getPointAtLength of an object which cannot be sent to the UI runtime. js engine: reanimated
Later, I used:
const geo = new PathGeometry(path);
const totalLength = geo.getTotalLength();
const pos = geo.getPointAtLength(0);
const posX = useSharedValue(pos.x);
const posY = useSharedValue(pos.y);
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
const nPos = geo.getPointAtLength(i);
posX.value = nPos.x;
posY.value = nPos.y;
i++;
}, 16);


It can work stiffly, but I know this is not a good solution because we cannot apply animation effects such as React Native Reanimated withSpring
May I know how to implement it? I am a beginner

Will you lemme know if you figure it out? I've been taking a crack at it and I think its kind of interesting

Finally succeeded, thanks to @PhantomSpooks for discussion and help！
Here is the successful js code, which includes an example of a curved path. You can switch pathStr to see the effect.
import { Canvas, Circle, Path, SkPath, Skia } from '@shopify/react-native-skia';
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';
import {
  cancelAnimation,
  interpolate,
  useDerivedValue,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

class PathGeometry {
  totalLength = 0;
  contour: SkContourMeasure;

  constructor(path: SkPath, resScale = 1) {
    const it = Skia.ContourMeasureIter(path, false, resScale);
    const contour = it.next();
    this.totalLength = contour.length();
    this.contour = contour;
  }

  getTotalLength() {
    return this.totalLength;
  }

  getPointAtLength(length) {
    const [pos] = this.contour.getPosTan(length);
    return pos;
  }
}

const pathStr =
  'M 128 0 L 168 80 L 256 93 L 192 155 L 207 244 L 128 202 L 49 244 L 64 155 L 0 93 L 88 80 L 128 0 Z';

// curve path
//const pathStr = 'M1 73C1 73 44 9 94 14C144 19 173 83 209 73C245 63 237 1 237 1';
const path = Skia.Path.MakeFromSVGString(pathStr);

const geo = new PathGeometry(path);
const totalLength = Math.floor(geo.getTotalLength());
const getPoints = (geo) => {
  let points = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) {
    let pos = geo.getPointAtLength(i);
    points.push({ x: pos.x, y: pos.y });
  }
  return points;
};
const points = getPoints(geo);

const SkiaRoot = () => {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const progress = useSharedValue(0);
  const currPoint = useDerivedValue(() => {
    const interpolatedIndex = interpolate(
      progress.value,
      [0, 1],
      [0, totalLength - 1]
    );
    const index = Math.floor(interpolatedIndex);
    return points[index];
  });

  const cx = useDerivedValue(() => currPoint.value.x);
  const cy = useDerivedValue(() => currPoint.value.y);

  const moveCircle = useCallback(() => {
    progress.value = withTiming(progress.value == 1 ? 0 : 1, {
      duration: 2000,
    });
  }, [width, height]);

  const stopAnimation = useCallback(() => {
    'worklet';
    cancelAnimation(progress);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Move" onPress={moveCircle} />
        <Button title="Stop" onPress={stopAnimation} />
        <Canvas style={{ width, height }}>
          <Path
            path={path}
            color="lightblue"
            style="stroke"
            strokeJoin="round"
            strokeWidth={2}
          />
          <Circle cx={cx} cy={cy} r={16} color="red" />
        </Canvas>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 5,
  },
});

export default SkiaRoot;


Im kinda of new to react native skia, so there could be easier ways to achieve your goal; but I would start by getting the points within the path:
export const addPoints = (point1:Point, point2:Point)=>{
  "worklet"
  return {
    x:point1.x + point2.x,
    y:point1.y + point2.y
  }
}

export const getPathPoints = (path:SkPath,offset?:Point)=>{
  "worklet"
  const initialPoint = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    ...(offset||{}),

  }
  const pathLength = path.countPoints()
  const points = Array(pathLength).fill(null).map((_,i)=>{
    const {x,y} = path.getPoint(i)
    return addPoints({x,y}, initialPoint)
  })
  return points
}

Now you can use withSequence to go to each point within the path. You can repeat this animation by wrapping withSequence within withRepeat. Of course, you'll need sharedvalues to run this animation:
import { getPathPoints } from "@/helpers/path";
import useLayout from "@/hooks/useLayout";
import { Canvas, Circle, Path, SkPath, Skia } from "@shopify/react-native-skia";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { cancelAnimation, useSharedValue, withRepeat, withSequence, withTiming } from "react-native-reanimated";
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

const r = 25;
const initialPoint = {
  x:r,
  y:r
}

const pathStr = "M 128 0 L 168 80 L 256 93 L 192 155 L 207 244 L 128 202 L 49 244 L 64 155 L 0 93 L 88 80 L 128 0 Z"
const path = Skia.Path.MakeFromSVGString(pathStr)! as SkPath;
const points = getPathPoints(path,)



const SkiaRoot = () => {
  //TODO: scale path down to view dimensions
 const [{width,height},onLayout] = useLayout()
 const cx = useSharedValue(initialPoint.x)
 const cy = useSharedValue(initialPoint.y)


 const moveCircle = useCallback(()=>{
   // move to circle path starting point
  cx.value = withTiming(points[0].x)
  cy.value = withTiming(points[0].y)
  cx.value = withRepeat(
    withSequence(
    ...points.map(({x})=>withTiming(x))
  ),-1,true)
  cy.value = withRepeat(
    withSequence(
    ...points.map(({y})=>withTiming(y))
  ),-1,true)
 },[width,height])
 const stopAnimation = useCallback(()=>{
  "worklet"
  cancelAnimation(cx)
  cancelAnimation(cy)
  cx.value=initialPoint.x;
  cy.value=initialPoint.y;
 },[])
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}onLayout={onLayout}>
      <Button title="Move" onPress={moveCircle}/>
      <Button title="Stop" onPress={stopAnimation}/>
        <Canvas style={{ width, height }}>
          <Path path={path} color="lightblue"/>
          <Circle cx={cx} cy={cy} r={r} color="red"/>
        </Canvas>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    margin:5
  }
})

export default SkiaRoot;


Thank you very much. Your method is very useful to me. I learned from your code that it is to split the path into multiple straight line animations and then operate them through queues.But if the path is a curved path, getPathPoints will contain a lot of points, which will also generate a lot of animations in the queue. I hope that red ball can apply React Native Reanimated smoothing animation to this curve.。

My idea is to use a shared value of progress, control the progress value through WithSpring, and then obtain the corresponding point of the path based on the progress value, and then set the position of the red ball, but I don't know how to implement it

I’d tried to take a progress driven approach where I interpolated the progress value to a point index but it I couldn’t get it to work

The only thing I found online for doing what you want was this https://onexception.dev/news/1279686/react-native-reanimated-skia-animated-shapes but because it treats reanimated as if it is the RN’s Animated API I assumed it was AI generated

Here's the code for the progress base animation attempt. I forget exactly how it doesnt work; but it definitely doesnt work https://playcode.io/1893956

I think I know why it doesn't work, because getPathPoints doesn't get continuous points, it only gets vertices, so the length of the array is only 11, and the indexes obtained according to the progress will become very wide, I think this should be the reason why it can't move.

Finally succeeded. The problem lies in the way of obtaining points. It needs to obtain the length of the path, obtain the corresponding length according to the progress, and then obtain the corresponding points. I added the successful code. Thank you for your help these days.
